# DNS resolution for '.com.au' type of domains

Tags: dns

How are domains like www.abc.com.au resolved?

The domain name contains a generic top level domain and a country code top level domain. Does the 'au' country code top level domain have a 'com' in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically the "com" in "com.au" isn't a generic top level domain (gtld) -- it just looks like one. The only TLD in this is the country code top level domain (ccTLD) of "au". Some TLDs allow for the registration of second level domains (e.g., google.com) while others add another  level (e.g., google.com.au).

Domains that are treated as if they were TLDs like "com.au" are called [public suffixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Suffix_List). This is outside the scope of DNS but browsers tend to treat them differently to avoid issues like overly broad cookies. For example, a cookie in the google.com.au space should not be shared with microsoft.com.au.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the "au" top level domain has a "com" in its hierarchy.